# Why is the current time of the animation always 0?

Tags: javascript, animation

I press one of the forw or back-buttons and then the run button, so the image goes in one of those directions, but when i try to log the currentTime, it just says 0 both times, why?...

```
    forw.onclick = ()=>{
        x = 630;
    }

    back.onclick = ()=>{
        x = -630;
    }

    run.onclick = ()=>{

        let animasjon = imgCar.animate([{
        transform: `translateX(0px)`
        },{
        transform: `translateX(${x}px)`
        }],{
        duration: 1000,
        fill: "forwards"
        })

        let cur = animasjon.currentTime

        setInterval(() => {
            console.log(cur)
        }, 1200);

    }
```

Comment: because `let cur = animasjon.currentTime` is not auto updating..... It stores the first value and that is what you get,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are instantiating the variable once, and it just logs that same value each time your interval is called. If you want it updated, you need to update it in the interval like:

```js
setInterval(() => {
   cur = animasjon.currentTime
   console.log(cur)
}, 1200);
```